# Add graphical annotations to a video e.g random drawings using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ffmpeg

I have developed a flutter app in which i am using FFmpeg library for video manipulation ,
**Actually i want to draw some random drawings in to a video and make it a part of the video**.
what i am already doing is that , i added some annotated images into a video by using ffmpeg library in flutter , but the problem with ffmpeg is that it is very time consuming ,it is taking almost 10sec for a 10sec video clip.

ffmpeg command i am using is:

```
ffmpeg.execute("-y -i input.mp4" " -i input.png -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2'\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4")
```

I want to do it as fast as whatsapp annotations...
any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You should provide some code with what you tried already.

Comment: question edited by adding  snippet that i had used in my code, Thanks @MarinaAguilar

Comment: So the actual question is how to make ffmpeg encode faster on Android?

Comment: @llogan , yes , how to encode faster , or is there any other alternative for encoding ?,
not exactly on android , but flutter....
if there are any native solutions , i can go for them too , i have to implement for both android and ios. thanks..

Comment: @Tahir You can add `-preset ultrafast`. Not much you can do other than that. ffmpeg doesn't yet support MediaCodec encoding. Perhaps you can do it with MediaCodec. Video encoding is complex and phones are not powerful enough to provide a faster encoding at the quality, speed, and resolution that you want when using non-hardware accelerated encoding. If you target devices support NEON you may get a significant speed boost but your x264 must be properly configured. Refer to the ffmpeg log and look for `using cpu capabilities`.

Comment: Thanks @llogan , i will try MediaCodec ,
One thing I must ask here is that , **what is the way WhatsApp,Snapchat type apps are using for there video annotation features** ? , are they using MediaCodecs for encoding , or some other methods ?
I am wondering for even a clue how to achieve that , i'll certainly take care of else part..
Thanks

Comment: I don't know how they do it and I doubt they are open with their methodology.

Comment: Ok , i'll try to find there methodology , until then , i'll try with Android [MediaCodecs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec)
Thanks @llogan.